# Utils class in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

I'd like to create an utility class in Angular.js that can be used by several controllers.

So far I created this:

```
'use strict';
angular
  .module('App')
  .factory('AppUtils', AppUtils);

function AppUtils() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.getPersonOf = getPersonOf;

  function getPersonOf(personId, allPersons) {
    var person = {};
    person.personId = {personId: personId};
    allPersons.forEach(function(p) {
      if (p.personId === personId) {
        person = p;
      }
    });
    return person;
  }

}
```

And I tried to use it in a controller like this:

```
'use strict';
angular
  .module('App')
  .controller('AppController', AppController);

function AppController(personId, allPersons, AppUtils) {

var vm = this;
vm.personId = personId;

vm.person = AppUtils.getPersonOf(vm.personId, allPersons);

...
}
```

But I get this:

> PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0) App should dismiss modal FAILED
>       Error: [$injector:undef] Provider 'AppUtils' must return a value from $get factory method.
>       http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/undef?p0=InvoiceUnitsUtils

(The real names have been renamed to make it easier.)

Why am I getting that error? Am I not declaring properly the Utility module?

Comment: That's not how one uses `factory`. What you're doing should be a `service`

Comment: You just need to `return vm;` at the end of factory.

Answer (score 1):

The factory is in charge of creating a service and handing its instance to you.  To do this, you need to return your utility class:

```
function AppUtils() {

     return { 
      getPersonOf: getPersonOf
     // pass other utility functions...
    }

    function getPersonOf(personId, allPersons) {
        var person = {};
        person.personId = {personId: personId};
        allPersons.forEach(function(p) {
            if (p.personId === personId) {
                person = p;
            }
        });
        return person;
     }
  }
```

I removed the `vm` part because we are handing a service which usually has no view model (the controller is in charge of that, service is more of a business logic expert).

Here's some more information about the `$get` function in Angular's providers:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers